# How do I choose a bridge camera for an aspiring photographer?

Tags: equipment-recommendation, bridge-camera

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I choose a bridge camera?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/17617/how-do-i-choose-a-bridge-camera)

I have to buy a new camera for my brother. He's not such as a expert to buy a reflex, I mean... not yet. So I'd like to buy a bridge camera, just to give him the possibility to do a little practise.

I have a Fuji s5700 and for me (I'm not a expert either.. it's just a passion by now) and I found it great... so I thought the Fuji s1900 could be ok for him. I'd like to ask you which are the features to look for in a bridge camera, and which one you can suggest for me.

Comment: @mattdm Not sure it can be a duplicate of something that was asked over a year later (the reverse is more likely)